# CRON Job to delete files (not folders) with specific extensions within a folder and subfolders

Tags: cron, dreamhost

I need a cron job that will delete all files with these extensions (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf) in a folder (including files in subfolders, but not the subfolders themselves) twice a day. I'm using Dreamhost which allows you to customize the frequency within their UI, so I believe I just need the command.

Because the files can take a minute or two to get processed upon upload for extra safety it would be nice if the job only deleted files that were at least 5 minutes old, but that is optional.

Thank you so much for your help - I'm new to cron jobs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find <path> \( -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.jpeg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.pdf \) -type f -mmin +5 -delete
```

For the explanation: `man find`.

Comment: So for the path, would I use an absolute path like this? 

find /home/server_name/example.com/wp-content/uploads/forms \( -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.jpeg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.pdf \) -type f -mmin +5 -delete

Comment: Yes. Consider testing this first, just drop `-delete` and examine the output. Please note backslashes are needed there (to escape shell metacharacters: `(`, `)` and `*`).

Comment: Ok, so it finds all the relevant files in the path that I specify, but not files in subfolders - any way to get those found as well?

Comment: Ok, added an "*" at the end of the directory path, and it picked up the files in subdirectories. 

Comment: That's a bit unexpected. Are you sure it is descending in all subdirectories? If not - try to drop `-type f` part from the command.

Comment: Is this not expected? If there's a file in this directory:  

/home/server_name/example.com/wp-content/uploads/forms/test/test.png THEN  

/home/server_name/example.com/wp-content/uploads/forms/* will find it with the conditions we set above?

However:

/home/server_name/example.com/wp-content/uploads/forms/ will not.

Comment: `-type f` means files only. I guess this is why it dropped the first level subdirectories but I am not 100% sure. For me it is a bit unexpected but honestly I didn't test it and and didn't think a lot about it - so I may have missed something. If it works - use it, if it doesn't - dig into manual and improve it.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought -f meant making it a foreground process. 

Anyways, thank you very much for all your help. I believe I have a workable solution now!